# Use XSLT to get modifications in old XML, then apply them in new XML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I think my problem is general enough to ask the question, but specific enough so nobody asked it yet - or I wasn't able to find it.

The task is the following: An application's configuration is stored inside an XML document. The application since then evolved and the current configuration is stored inside a different XML. The new XML is different in structure as well, so simply copying the old config will break the application.
Our goal is simple: We want to move the configuration changes from the old XML document into the new one. We have access to:

- Non-modified old XML
- Modified old XML
- Non-modified new XML

From this information above I have to create the new XML document, where the modifications inside the old xml are re-applied.

I've figured out the algorithm already, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel here. The high level algorithm is the following:

- Compare each node inside the non-modified XML with the modified XML.

  - If the node is not modified move forward.
  - If a node is removed copy it's xpath location to the removed-nodes collection.
  - If a node is added move it's xpath location and it's content into the added-nodes collection.
  - If a node is modified, move the modified atomic content / attribute to the modified-nodes collection
  - If a node is not atomic, apply the above algorithm to every descendant node. (recursive algorithm)
- Open the new XML, go to each modification location, and

  - Remove the deleted nodes
  - Add the added nodes
  - Apply the modifications

The xml layout of the collected modification would look like something like this:

```
<xml-diff>
    <added-node location="/xpath/to/the/node">
        <content-of-the-added-node with="attributes">
            <and-sub-elements-as-well/>
        </content-of-the-added-node>
    </added-node>
    <removed-node location="/xpath/to/the/node"/>
    <modified-node location="/xpath/to/the/node">
        <content-of-the-modified-node>modified-atomic-content</content-of-the-modified-node>
    </modified-node>
    <added-attribute location="/xpath/to/the/@attribute">value</added-attribute>
    <removed-attribute location="/xpath/to/the/@attribute" />
    <modified-attribute location="/xpath/to/the/@attribute">new-value</added-attribute>        
</xml-diff>
```

content-of-the-added-node and content-of-the-modified-node are both nodes inside the modified old xml.

After locating the modifications inside the old xml, the task is pretty straight forward. I can re-apply the modifications inside the new xml where the xpath doesn't changed. I also have a mapping which describes what old xpath value has been changed to what new xpath value, thus applying the configuration changes correctly. (For example /root/node1 has moved to /root/collections/node1, etc.)

I know that XSLT is used for transforming one XML to another. The tricky part here is to detect what are the modifications - transformations are. Sadly processing XML is a bit tricky since the order of the nodes is not always kept, but it still can mean the same thing nonetheless.

My questions are:

1. Is XSLT the right path to approach this problem, or should I use something else?
2. If XSLT is, what is the right transformation algorithm to detect these changes recursively?
3. If XSLT isn't the answer what is?
4. Can you provide me a simple XSLT where I can begin my work with?

Please note that I'm totally new in XSLT. I'm familiar with XML, and have some basic understanding of XSD.

Comment: This does not seem to be something where automation via XSLT is required or warranted. How often is this happening? Once a day? Month? For how many things? ONe application? 100,000 applications? There are very good Diff/Exmaine/Hand Merge tools including those built into tools like oXygen or Stylus that would seem to suffice.

Comment: @KevinBrown Maybe it seem to suffice, but it doesn't. This solution would be a part of an upgrade process from version 1 to version 2. And when the time comes, from version 2 to version 3 etc. I don't insist on using XSLT, I only want to apply the diff. If you have a better approach, I'm all ears.

Comment: Well, if you have the "xml-diff" file above, applying those changes is likely best for code and not XSL. That said, use source code control to manage "source code" and let it handel it ... and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @KevinBrown Frankly, I don't understand what are you talking about.  What source code control? My main question was: how to acquire the xml-dif file with xslt - or some other, but programable mean - from the non-modified and modified files.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. If you have not managed the changes in any "controlled" way, then applying the changes are likely not an automated process -- or possibly we don;t have all the information -- Example: You have "modifed old XML" -- can they be anything by different people? Some deleted something, some moved it to the end, some changed the structure.

Comment: @KevinBrown The difference is restricted in two ways: There are parts of the xml where attributes / values can be replaced, but not the node itself. (The value can be set to null ofc). The other part is a collection of items. Here the user can add / remove items from the collection. But the structure has to be intact. The main problem is that the old and new xml have a slightly modified structure, so copy / paste will break the application itself.